# MX Google Map's search functionality not returning results for existing locations

Tags: mx-google-map

I'm using MX Google Map to map various locations. However, when I use the `{exp:mx_google_map:form}` and `{exp:mx_google_map:search}` I can't return any results. I verified the information is filled out in the entry, but doing a search for the same zip code returns no results and the template debugger outputs this information:

```
(0.011036 / 6.35MB) Tag: {exp:mx_google_map:search channel="glo-con" reverse_geocoding="true" address="" long="" lat="" unit="" radius="500" prec="2" prefix="" address_fields="address"}
(0.011161 / 6.36MB) Closing Tag Found
(0.011209 / 6.36MB) Processing Tags
(0.011244 / 6.37MB) Module Tag: Mx_google_map/search
(0.011260 / 6.37MB) Including Files for Plugins and Modules
(0.012097 / 7.28MB) Files for Plugins and Modules All Included
(0.012724 / 7.31MB) Beginning Final Tag Data Processing
(0.012749 / 7.31MB) Calling Class/Method: Mx_google_map/search
(0.012966 / 7.31MB) -> Class Called: Mx_google_map
(0.013003 / 7.32MB) -> Method Called: search
(0.070547 / 9.99MB) Returning No Results Content
(0.070693 / 9.98MB) -> Data Returned
```

My **/contact** page:

```
{exp:mx_google_map:form result_page="/contact/results" long="" lat="" unit=""}
    <div>
        <label>Address<br>
            <input name="address" type="text">
        </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Radius<br>
            <select name="radius">
                <option value="100">100</option>
                <option value="50" selected="selected">50</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:mx_google_map:form}
```

My **/contact/results** page:

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>
{exp:mx_google_map:search channel="glo-con" reverse_geocoding="true" address="" long="" lat="" unit="" radius="500" prec="2" prefix="" address_fields="address"}

    {entries}
        {glo-con-map}<li>{title}</li>{/glo-con-map}
    {/entries}

{/exp:mx_google_map:search}
```

Am I missing something *very* obvious?

**Version information:**

- ExpressionEngine 2.5.4
- MX Google Maps 1.4

Comment: Aarron, in your profiler (above the debugger assuming you have it turned on) look at the queries for the page. Find the query related to the search. My guess...I think you will find that the zip code is missing, which suggests you havent defined the address_fields correctly. The docs for the plugin dont look the best.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to find what I _believe_ is the query for MX Google Maps. However, there's no reference to the zip code I typed in the form. Here's [the query](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d95e03233e8cd64f31c3)

Comment: Aaron, i dont think thats the query. Anyway, it appears the support for MX google maps is dead. I use Geotagger + Geofinder plugins to do what you are after. Yes, its paid, but it works and is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated MX Google Map to the latest version to get this to work. (D'oh!)